# Program cannot read xlsx file until it has been saved by Excel

Tags: c#, excel, xls, file-format

We have an application that uses the Microsoft Access Database Engine to read data from an Excel xlsx file. The xlsx file is generated by third party software. The application has been working fine for years.

The company that generates the xlsx file has modified their software, with the result that the format of the xlsx file has changed. Our application can no longer read those files.
However, if I manually open one of these files using Excel, and immediately click 'Save', the new file works fine.

The response from the third party is basically "Since you can open the file using Excel, then that shows it is a valid xlsx file. The problem must be on your end". They do have a point.

I have posted a sample of one of these xlsx files at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6jNYMkptFteTmc4YU9BWU1PRUk/edit?usp=sharing

Here is a simple test program (a Console Application in VisualStudio.net) that reproduces the problem.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String fileSpec = @"C:\Temp\TestData-Original.xlsx";
    String connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileSpec + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1\"";

    DataTable dtExcelRecords = null;

    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;

    OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

    try
    {
        con.Open();       // Throws exception here.

        DataTable dtExcelSheetNames = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

        String sheetName = (dtExcelSheetNames.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString()).Replace("''", "'");
        if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(sheetName)))
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";
            dtExcelRecords = new DataTable();
            dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            dAdapter.Fill(dtExcelRecords);
        }
        con.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Found {0} records in file {1}", dtExcelRecords.Rows.Count, fileSpec));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

If you run this program with the sample Excel file, it will fail.
If you open the sample file in Excel, and click 'Save', and then run the program, it will read the file successfully.

The test program makes 2 assumptions: (1) The xlsx file is located at C:\Temp\TestData-Original.xlsx and (2) The Microsoft Access database Engine is installed on your computer.

I have researched this, but have had no luck. Most of the discussion revolves around changing the connection string to specify different versions of Excel. Nothing so far has made any difference.

Note: I noticed that when I open the file using Excel, and then save it, the size increases by about 70%.

Any ideas?

Comment: `If you run this program with the sample Excel file, it will fail.` how does it fail? Does it give an exception? If so, what is it? What does it say? If you step through the code in the debugger what happens?

Comment: Can the third party provide you with the *exact* file format used?  "Excel file" is, as you can imagine, somewhat vague.  Excel can open plain text files, but that hardly demonstrates that plain text is a valid xlsx file.  If you open the before and after files in a plain text editor do they have some internal XML which specifies format information?

Comment: have you done a before/after comparison of the files? Theoretically if you don't do anything in excel and just save it out again, there should be only very minor changes to the file (e.g. updating total-time-edited, last-edited-by, etc... counters). Compare them and see what's happening.

Comment: @MarcB: Actually the difference can be pretty substantial depending on how the file was generated. A simple example is that you can either put strings directly in cells in an XLSX file, or you can use the string table. When you open the file in Excel and save it again, Excel will most likely pull out those inline strings and put them in the string table for you.

Comment: Another note, `.xlsx` files are just `.zip` files. You can change the extension to `zip` and unpack them. Might be useful to do that and compare the various (mainly xml) files inside.

Comment: @MarcB: Another example is with cell styles. You can repeat the same style multiple times when generating an `xlsx` file and Excel will likely condense them for you.

Comment: @EHeaney try open xlsx with [Closed Xml](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I'm struggling to imagine what kind of answer are you hoping to get other than suggestions you should abandon the OleDB approach and use OpenXML SDK or similar approach to just read the XML in that xslx. OleDB is the most bizarre way I've seen to access an excel sheet's data

Comment: @Max ClosedXML was the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Sten Petrov: Struggle no more! The kind of answers I was hoping to get were from MarcB and from Max. Yes indeed, XML makes life easier. However, we originally opted to use OleDB as we have to handle various xls* files, including the pre-XML kind.

Comment: @EHeaney Ahhh the relief! the struggle is over :) I wish MarcB had made his comment an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have use [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) (a wrapper for OpenXML) without problem.

```
    string fileSpec = @"C:\Temp\TestData-Original.xlsx";

    var wb = new XLWorkbook(fileSpec);
    var ws = wb.Worksheet("Sheet1");

    MessageBox.Show(ws.RowCount().ToString());
```

Comment: I recently came across a similar problem and posted it here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26006514/microsof-office-2010-will-not-open-two-xls 
I am having problem with office 2010 when trying to open two xls files.